# how to configure swagger UI to allow user to entry multiple values for query string parameter

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, swagger, swagger-ui

I am using `django-rest-swagger==2.1.2` and `djangorestframework==3.7.7` and I have a view that looks like this:

```
class PendingRequests(generics.GenericAPIView):
    ...
    filter_backends = (PendingRequestsFilter,)

    def get(self, request):
        ...
        request_status = request.GET.getlist('status')
        request_start_date = request.GET.get('start_date')
        request_end_date = request.GET.get('end_date')
        ...
```

and I have defined a filter like so:

```
class PendingRequestsFilter(BaseFilterBackend):
    def get_schema_fields(self, view):
        fields = [
            coreapi.Field(name="status", description="Statuses of the Requests", required=False, location='query', example='active'),
            coreapi.Field(name="status", description="Statuses of the Requests", required=False, location='query', example='pending'),
            coreapi.Field(name="status", description="Statuses of the Requests", required=False, location='query', example='inactive'),
            coreapi.Field(name="start_date", description="Start Date of the Request (YYYY-MM-DD)", required=False, location='query', example='2525-12-25'),
            coreapi.Field(name="end_date", description="End Date of the Request (YYYY-MM-DD)", required=False, location='query', example='2525-12-26'),
        ]
        return fields
```

This results in my swagger UI for this view looking like this:

[image]

But when I enter different status like so ...

[image]

... and click 'try it out' I get a Request URL that looks like this:

```
http://myserver:4800/api/v1/sudorequests/requests/?status=pending&status=pending&status=pending
```

Note that `status=pending` is repeated three times. I wanted to get a Request URL that looks more like this:

```
http://myserver:4800/api/v1/sudorequests/requests/?status=inactive&status=active&status=pending
```

Comment: Which version of Django are you using?

Comment: Nevermind I managed to reproduce your problem

Comment: Thanks! I suspect it is a bug with Swagger UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have some insights that may help you.

[Swagger Spec](http://docs.swagger.io/spec.html) mentions `allowMultiple` setting in paragraph `5.2.4 Parameter Object`

> `allowMultiple`   Another way to allow multiple values for a
>   “query” parameter. If used, the query parameter may accept
>   comma-separated values. The field may be used only if paramType is
>   "query", "header" or "path".

That might what you want

I tried passing it to `coreapi.Field` as such:

`coreapi.Field(name="status", description="Statuses of the Requests", required=False, location='query', example='active', allowMultiple=True)`

but it doesn't work

Next I searched through `swagger-ui.js` and discovered this line

```
var isArray = paramType.toLowerCase() === 'array' || param.allowMultiple;
```

Luckily for us `coreapi.Field` is just a [namedtuple](https://github.com/core-api/python-client/blob/d264fd277a878ea40f9f75755e461f8a9418671f/coreapi/document.py#L49), which passes all necessary params to swagger up. It looks like this:

```
Field = namedtuple('Field', ['name', 'required', 'location', 'schema', 'description', 'type', 'example'])
Field.__new__.__defaults__ = (False, '', None, None, None, None)
```

My idea is to extend it and use it instead of `coreapi.Field`. I'm monkeypatching because some `coreapi.Document` and `coreapi.Link` logic forces us to.

```
coreapi.Field = namedtuple('Field', coreapi.Field._fields + ('allowMultiple',))
coreapi.Field.__new__.__defaults__ = (False, '', None, None, None, None, False)
```

and then use it like this:

```
coreapi.Field(name="status", description="Statuses of the Requests", required=False, location='query', example='active', allowMultiple=True)
```

Unfortuantely still there is an error, but I decided to post it anyway. Maybe together we can figure it out.
I'm still working on it and feel that i'm almost there.

**EDIT**

I've tried to overcome the error but it slowly becomes apparent that if you really need that feature it would be easier to just fork `coreapi` library and edit `Field` as i showed above.

Comment: What file did you put your patch into?

Comment: just above `class PendingRequestsFilter(BaseFilterBackend):`

Comment: ah you had a link to it: https://github.com/core-api/python-client/blob/d264fd277a878ea40f9f75755e461f8a9418671f/coreapi/document.py#L49

Comment: I've forked the coreapi repo and modified Field. Still no success.
Looks like allowMultiple is not passed as spec to swagger-ui

Comment: If I were to open an issue on github should I open on core-api/python-client or should I create an issue for Swagger UI's github?

Comment: Looks like on both. Unfortunately

Comment: I have opened an issue against swagger UI on github: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/4918

Comment: They pointed me to Django-rest-swagger GitHub https://github.com/marcgibbons/django-rest-swagger/issues/779

Comment: Sadly looks like a problem that will not be solved anytime soon.